# iOS Xcode Importing COLLADA .dae 3D Model from Maya While Respecting Pivot Points

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, 3d, collada

I'm exporting a 3D model hierarchy from Maya as a .dae. Each element in this hierarchy has a local pivot point. However when brought into Xcode each object in the hierarchy has its pivot point moved to world zero. I can't work out how get the elements in, respecting their local pivot points. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Bake the pivot/s in Maya before exporting.

Comment: Do you mean Maya's 'Freeze Transfoms'?

Comment: No, it's actually bellow "freeze transformations". It's called exactly "Bake pivots." This can introduce issues if you've animated already unfortunately.

Comment: UPDATE: I found a different way which doesn't mess with the animation. When you are exporting the file to Collada (FBX/Collada), uncheck "Single Matrix".